# Effortless Mindfulness

Tags: mindfulness

Am currently taking Tricycle course on Effortless mindfulness.  The concept of being aware of awareness is difficult for me.  Any ideas to help achieve being aware of awareness during meditation as a type of "advanced" basic mindfulness?

Comment: Mindfulness or 'sati' does not mean 'awareness' therefore Tricycle appears off to a bad start. 'Mindfulness' means 'to remember', most specifically, to remember to practise the Buddhist path.

Answer (score 4):

Mindfulness does not mean awareness.

The above said, attempting to be *aware of awareness* is excessive effort. Trying to do this may possibly make one crossed-eyed or give one a headache.

Right effort in formal meditation is simply to establish the mind in quietude or silence. For example, at the very end of the [Anapanasati Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.118.than.html), it is said right mindfulness depends on quietude (solitude from unwholesome mental states; *viveka*), fading away (*viraga*), cessation (*nirodha*) & matures as giving up attachment or surrender (*vossagga*).

The quiet mind is naturally aware because the nature of the mind or consciousness is to be aware of something. If a practitioner uses too much effort, that excessive effort will become an obscuration to clear awareness.

Answer (score 1):

It's much smarter to seek for getting in touch with the teachings of the Sublime Buddha, seeking out for the Sangha (of monks), then to rely on teachings traders [for money] give. There is no such as effortless mindfulness, since it actually requires a lot of, even [right effort](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-ditthi/index_en.html), used for abandoning wrong view. Blessed those who don't meet cheaters.

Answer (score 1):

I have just recently found a repetition that has proven extremely helpful for me to expand my awareness of the moment or mindfulness.

I set my cell phone to signal for one minute at the top of each hour. No matter what I am doing at that moment I become mindful of what I am doing. I breathe deep and slow, focusing, being aware.

The effects are very encouraging. My mindfulness is extending beyond one minute and I am able to involve the moment much more easily. Monkey chatter is eliminated and bliss sometimes makes me smile.

Is it necessary to wrestle over the meaning of mindfulness, awareness, or living in the moment? I am not so sure.